# How should I properly represent multi-variable complexity with Google benchmark?

Tags: google-benchmark

The Google microbenchmark library supports estimating complexity of an algorithm but everything is expressed by telling the framework what the size of your `N` is. I'm curious what the best way  to represent `M+N` algorithms in this framework is. In my test I go over a cartesian product of M & N values in my test.

Do I call `SetComplexityN` with `M+N` (& for `O(MN)` algorithms I assumed `SetComplexityN` is similarly `M*N`)? If I wanted to hard-code the complexity of the algorithm (vs doing best fit) does `benchmark::oN` then map to `M+N` and `benchmark::oNSquared` maps to `O(MN)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something we've yet considered in the library.

If you set the complexity to `M+N` and use `oN` then the fitting curve used for the minimal least square calculation will be linear in `M+N`.

However, if you set the complexity to `M*N` and use `oNSquared` then we'll try to fit to `pow(M*N, 2)` which is likely not what you want, so I think still using `oN` would be appropriate.